# How to split window at sublime2 at the vintage mode on Mac

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to split window in sublime text editor.

```
{
    "keys": ["sp"],
            # I don't know how to call split window command. Please help!
    "command": "split_window_horizontaly",
    "context": [
        {"key": "setting.command_mode","operand": false},
        {"key": "setting.is_widget","operand": false}
    ]
    },
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the keys are a list of keys. So for the above key combination you would want something like `["s", "p"]`. To manually do the splits, you would have to call the `set_layout` command with the appropriate arguments. You can see the commands that run when you use the menu by opening the console and entering `sublime.log_commands(True)`.

With that being said, doing it yourself can be more trouble than it's worth. Take a look at the [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami) plugin and the [Vintage-Origami](https://github.com/garyc40/Vintage-Origami) plugin. The Origami plugin gives some better pane management commands. The Vintage-Origami plugin creates keybindings that can be used in vintage mode. If you don't like those bindings, you can use it as a guide to create bindings that you do like.

Hope that helps.